# Why use an extern "C" around a C++ namespace

Tags: c++, c, gcc

A few days back, I came across this piece of C++ code, though I can't paste the code itself, I could recreate the problem with some sample code.
First, the file, namespace.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace useless{
  class X {
     int m_myint;
     static X *m_foobar;
     X* getPrivVal(void);
  public:
     int getMember(void);
     X* getStaticVal(void);
  };
}
```

Next, `namespace.cpp`:

```
#include "namespace.h"

extern "C"{
   namespace useless{
     X* X::m_foobar = NULL;
     X* X::getPrivVal(void){
         if(m_foobar == NULL)
             m_foobar = new X;
         return(m_foobar);
     }
   }
}

namespace useless {
   int X::getMember(void){
       if(m_myint == 0)
           m_myint = 1;
      return(m_myint);
   }
   X* X::getStaticVal(void){
        return(getPrivVal());
   }
}

using namespace useless;

int main(void){
    X y;
    cout << "The int value is " << y.getMember() << endl;
    cout << "The value of the static member is " << y.getStaticVal() << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

This code compiled and linked fine when I used g++ 3.4.3, but gives the following error when I use g++ 4.x, I have tried with GCC 4.6.1 as well GCC 4.2.1. Have tried it on Linux as well as Mac, same results.

This is the error(Suse):

```
g++ -o namespace namespace.cpp
namespace.h:8:15: error: previous declaration of useless::X* 
    useless::X::m_foobar with C++ linkage
namespace.cpp:5:11: error: conflicts with new declaration with C linkage
```

Can someone please shed some light on what the legacy C++ code was looking to do, could this have been a hack or workaround to get around an old problem that I am not aware of any longer. Ohh by the way, the method inside the `extern "C"` is called by C++ code and not any C code as I initially suspected. 
FYI, this is legacy code now, may have been written in 2001/2002 period.

---

Thanks guys. I have gone ahead and got rid of the extern "C" with no major impact.
@Bjorn Pollex : The guy who wrote that code is long gone.

Comment: If this code is version-controlled, check the history to find whoever wrote that, and hit them with a stick until they repent their sins.

Answer (score 14):

The `extern "C"` directive has two effects, it disables mangling when possible and uses the C calling convention. In this particular case, because there is a namespace in between, name mangling cannot be disabled, so it could have been added to force a particular calling convention.

The code is actually wrong in that the declaration does not force `extern "C"` but the definition does, which is incorrect. Consider that if the compiler just followed the directive as shown, the caller would use C++ naming and calling conventions, while the function would be using the C variant, if the two differ the result will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like an attempt to generate the variables witout C++ name mangling. That's one part of using `extern "C"`.

The newer compiler obviously realizes that it really doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a piece of C++ code that you want to call from a module written in another language (C, FORTRAN or whatever), you want to turn off C++ name mangling.

**Edit:**
The really weird thing is that they did it on the definition but not on the declaration. It's a wonder that it ever compiled

Comment: Turning off name mangling doesn't make sense when you're talking about C++-exclusive features like classes and namespaces.